# Find key based length of values in dict

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, max

I have `dict` like follows:

```
a = {'abc':[0,1,2], 'def':[0,1,2,3,4], 'ghi':[0,1,2,3,4,5]}
```

Want to get the `key` based on the `max` length of the array contains. As in here,
out put would be `'ghi'`. Anybody how to do it. I have tried:

`lambda x: max(len(x[1])), a.items()` 
but it doesn't solve the purpose. Can anyone tell what should I do?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

`max(a, key=lambda x: len(a[x]))`

Comment: Thanks. That'll do. Let me check for other scenarios.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
a = {'abc':[0,1,2], 'def':[0,1,2,3,4], 'ghi':[0,1,2,3,4,5]}

print(list(a.keys())[list(a.values()).index(max(a.values()))])
```